# Issue in WFFM CD Form submission data not saving to custom db 8.1 update 3

Tags: wffm, scaling

I am currently working with `WFFM` installation on Sitecore 8.1 update 3, which is working fine upto ProdCM but data from the form submission in live Environment were not saving to custom DB

I have followed documentation for installing `WFFM` in `CD` Environment from sitecore.

I have already double confirmed the config changes in from `CD` Environment as per the documentation

We were having separate core databases for `CM` and `CD` Environment Does it break the functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In WFFM, Save Actions are queued as Events and processed in CM. Since the Core databases are different, enable **Client Action** setting in Save Action item

Comment: this did the trick, thank you